# Reading next line from data file VB Script

Tags: vbscript, data-files

I am trying to get the next line of data tag file, however because there are multiple lines with the same tag it is going through and taking the last one but I need the first one. Example tag file below.

```
Summary SA2100|7775555
Summary SUM100|9674555
Summary SUM100|8544555
Summary SUM100|8555554
```

From this it is taking 8555554 and not 7775555.

I was trying to put the first line in the if condition and set the string to be the next line is this possible ?

```
if Left(strLine, 14) = "Summary SA2100" Then
        strSummary = mid(strNextLine, 16, 7)
End If
```

Is there a way to use StrNextLine or something similar ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to something like this:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\scripts\servers.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
    MsgBox strNextLine
Loop
```

[***VbsEdit***](http://www.vbsedit.com): I don't like to recommend tools, but [vbsedit.com](http://www.vbsedit.com) has a trial version that keeps partially working with no license. I think it will help you a lot. I personally use it as a light-weight way to quickly check COM object properties and methods.

[***Sample Library***](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/default.asp): Moreover, and this is the really important part, they have a large sample library that you can search whenever you need a quick hint on how to do useful stuff. [See the sample gallery](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/default.asp). The above snippet is adapted from [this sample](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/misc/input/scr_1230.asp).

There is a menu inside the application that allows quick searching of the whole library, or you can search it online. In the application you search via: **`Samples`** => **`Search Samples...`**. You get this dialog:

[image: VbsEdit Samples]

---

**UPDATE**:

Change the path to your data file - obviously. In the `OpenTextFile` method.

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\test.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strNextLine = objTextFile.ReadLine

    If Left(strNextLine, 14) = "Summary SA2100" Then
        strSummary = mid(strNextLine, 16, 7)
        MsgBox strSummary
        Exit Do
    End If

    'MsgBox strNextLine
Loop
```

Comment: I tried the suggested above, but it worked in the same way my own code did. i.e read the data from the last Summary tag (8555554) as apposed to the first (7775555)

Comment: I added another snippet.

Comment: No it still does not work, I cannot use an Exit at that part of the code as there are more lines to be read and exiting stops those.

Comment: Did you try to remove that Exit? You can add more **Ifs** or a **Select Case** to do different stuff based on the value you find.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  'create object to open file
Set txtFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt")   'full path for your file

 Do while Not txtFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine = txtFile.ReadLine

    If InStr(1,strLine,"Summary SA2100",1) > 0 Then
      strNextLine=txtFile.ReadLine
        nxtLine= mid(strNextLine, 16, 7)
        Exit Do 
    End If
loop
   MsgBox "The First Line : "& mid(strLine,16,7) & vbcrlf & "The Next Line : " & nxtLine
```