# How to get Department information from Active Directory using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am not a scripter of any kind, just a network specialist trying to get some domain information.

I have a domain with multiple OUs, multiple Security Groups as normal. I am trying to populate the 'Department:' field (under Organisation tab) of the user account in AD based on their being a member of specific security groups in the domain.

The code I am using is here:

```
{
On Error Resume Next

Set objGroup = GetObject _
    ("LDAP://CN=LiveTimeCustomers,OU=Service Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com", group)
' WScript.Echo objGroup.Name

For Each objMember In objGroup.Members
    ' WScript.Echo vbCrlf & "    Name: " & objMember.Name
    arrGroups = objMember.GetEx("memberOf")
    If (Err.Number = 0) Then
        On Error GoTo 0 
          strGroups = LCase(Join(arrGroups))
' Update Department attribute for COMMUNITY SECTION members           

        If InStr(strGroups, "cn=community section,ou=community,ou=organisation,dc=domain,dc=com") Then 
            ' WScript.Echo vbCrlf & "    Name: " & objMember.Name & " is member of COMMUNITY SECTION"
            Set objUser = GetObject(objMember.ADsPath)
            objUser.department = "COMMUNITY SECTION"
            objUser.SetInfo
        End If

}
```

The error I am getting when running is:

> Line: 23 Char: 5 The directory property cannot be found in the cache. 
>   Line and character is referring to this: arrGroups = objMember.GetEx("memberOf")

Answer (score 0):

I can't test AD stuff on this rig. However, as I described in this answer: [Reading next line from data file VB Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329543/reading-next-line-from-data-file-vb-script) this [**samples library**](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/default.asp) might help you.

The top category is "*Active Directory*" as you will see. [**Could this particular script help**](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/ad/groups/scr_33.asp)?

I'll inline the script sample for reference:

```
' List All the Members of a Group
On Error Resume Next

Set objGroup = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://cn=Scientists,ou=R&D,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")
objGroup.GetInfo

arrMemberOf = objGroup.GetEx("member")

WScript.Echo "Members:"
For Each strMember in arrMemberOf
    WScript.echo strMember
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is not to do it in vbscript! Thanks for help anyway.
After advise to update this script to Powershell, I did that. I needed to run a 'launch' script to run PS as administrator, and call the script that I want to edit AD with.

Launch script: 
`Start-Process powershell '-NoProfile -File \\domain.com\SYSVOL\domain.com\scripts\SetDepartmentAttribute.ps1' -verb RunAs`

Active Directory code:

```
    `Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "COMMUNITY"| Set-ADUser -Replace @{Department="COMMUNITY"}`
```

All this is providing your Execution Policy on DC allows for scripts to be run - check that out.